# Digitizing two layers of same table with different projection Fails in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

When I try to digitize two layers of different projection coming from the same table fails to digitize.  I am using a PostGIS table as a data source. The table has two geometry columns with different projection, which I want to digitize. What happens is the following:

1. When I add layer 1, it works in digitizing.
2. Then when I add the second one while the first one is there, the second one work.
3. But when I get back to layer 1, it draws an invalid geometry.

Unfortunately, after that, key things do not work, especially `featureAdded` and `beforeCommitChanges` signal and `layer.rollBack()`. 
I am using a custom form by supressing the default one using `curr_layer.editFormConfig().setSuppress(1)` this stops working. When I save data , I use `beforeCommitChanges` to do the saving directly using SQLAlchemy. Then I excute the undo stack so that QGis thinks there is nothing to save. However, it ignores beforeCommitChanges also try to save the same feature.

It there any known issue in this regard and a solution?

Comment: What does "coming from the same table" mean?

Comment: coming from the same table means. I am using a PostGIS table as a data source. The table has two geometry columns with different projection, which I want to digitize.

Comment: QGIS is not built to handle mixed projections in the same datasource. So what you experience is neither a bug nor a feature.

Comment: That is what I was also suspecting but I was able to digitize both layers open with the default Editor form.